# How to define active widget with js in a customizer

Tags: customization, widgets

I need to use js to define the identifier of the active (open / editable) widget.

+

Catch the event (trigger) switch the active widget.

Is there a built-in js api for these events?

I need something like this:

```
 jQuery(document).on('widget-updated', function(event, widget){
 //...
 });
jQuery(document).on('widget-added', function(event, widget){
 //...
 });
```

Or js object (view) with this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in the source code the answer to my question, maybe someone will come in handy:

```
jQuery(document).on('expand', function (event) {
        console.log(event.target);
});
```